# Embedding of $W^{1,\infty}$ in $C^{0,1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lipschitz-functions, holder-spaces

Theorem 5 of pag 283 of the text "Partial Differential Equations - Second Edition (Lawrence C. Evans)" states

> Let $U$ be a bounded, open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and suppose $\partial U$ is $C^1$. Assume $n < p \leq \infty$ and $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$.
>
> Then $u$ has a version $u^* \in C^{0,\gamma}(\overline{U})$, for $\gamma := 1 - \frac{n}{p}$, with the estimate
>
> \begin{equation} ||u^*||_{C^{0,\gamma}(\overline{U})} \leq C||u||_{W^{1,p}(U)}\end{equation}
>
> The costant $C$ depends only on $p,n$ and $U$

Where $u^*$ is a version of $u$ means that $u^*(x) = u(x)$ almost everywhere for $x \in U$, and

\begin{equation}||u^*||_{C^{0,\gamma}(\overline{U})} := sup_{x \in \overline{U}}{|u^*(x)|} + sup_{\substack{x,y \in U \\ x \neq y}}{\frac{|u^*(x)-u^*(y)|}{|x - y|^\gamma}}\end{equation}

The book proves the theorem in the case $p < \infty$ and says "The case $p = \infty$ is easy to prove directly".

I'm **only** interested in the case $p = \infty$.

I only managed to prove that there is a costant $C$ and that $u$ has a version $u^*$ such that

$$\sup_{x \in \overline{U}}{|u^*(x)|} \leq C||u||_{W^{1,\infty}(U)}$$

I don't understand how to prove that

$$ sup_{\substack{x,y \in \overline{U} \\ x \neq y}}{\frac{|u^*(x)-u^*(y)|}{|x - y|}} \leq C||u||_{W^{1,\infty}(U)}$$

Note that there is no hypothesis about the connection of $U$.

My question is : How can I prove the teorem in an easy way in the case $p = \infty$ ?

Comment: Hint: Write explicitly what $\|u\|_{W^{1, \infty}(U)}$ is.

Comment: @MattE. $||u||_{W^{1,\infty}(U)} =ess\sup_{x \in U}{|u(x)|} + ess\sup_{x \in U}{| Du(x)|}$

Comment: The problem is that $Du(x)$ is the vector of the **weak** first derivatives of $u$ so I can't use things like the Lagranges's MVT

Comment: Oh yes, you're correct. Good point. In that case you can observe that the inequality is true for test functions on $U$. Then you can use that test functions are dense in $W^{1, \infty}(U)$ to obtain the inequality you want.

Comment: @MattE. Test functions aren't dense in $W^{1, p}(U)$ (because they vanish at the boundary), though $C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$ is dense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt. Since $U$ is bounded, we have $W^{1, \infty} \subset W^{1, q}$ for all $q$, so we already know that $u$ is continuous. Denote by $u_1$ an extension of $u$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ that satisfies $\|u_1\|_{W^{1, \infty}} \leq C\|u\|_{W^{1, \infty}}$. Let $\eta \geq 0$ be the "standard mollifier". For $h > 0$, let $u_{h} = \eta_h * u_1$. Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be arbitrary. We have by the fundamental theorem of calculus and $Du_h = \eta_h * Du_1$ that
$$|u_h(x) - u_h(y)| \leq \|Du_{h}\|_{L^\infty}|x - y| \leq \|Du_1\|_{L^\infty}|x - y|.$$
Since $u$ is continuous on $U$, we have $u_{h} \to u$ locally uniformly on $U$, so if $x, y \in U$ we can take $h \searrow 0$ to get
$$|u(x) - u(y)| \leq \|Du_1\|_{L^\infty}|x - y| \leq C\|Du\|_{L^\infty}|x - y|.$$
This shows that $u$ is in fact Lipschitz, as desired.

Comment: How do you prove that $\lim_{h \downarrow 0}{||Du_h||_{L^\infty}} = ||Du_1||_{L^\infty}$ ?

Comment: @Paul I didn't use that. I used $\|f * g\|_{L^{\infty}} \leq \|f\|_{L^1}\|g\|_{L^{\infty}}$